# How to hide half of a div in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

```
<div class="more">
<p>
  Your trip originates&nbsp;in Buffalo Narrows&nbsp;where you are flown via
charter floatplane to Vermilion Lake. Vermilion and other nearows&nbsp;where you are flown via
charter floatplane to Vermilion Lake. Vermilion and other nearby
lakes&nbsp;provide a variety&nbsp;of terrain and adventure, and are abundant
with walleye, lake trout and northern pike.
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
</p>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Configure/customize these variables.
var animation_time = 1000;  // this
var showChar = 300;  // How many characters are shown by default
var b = showChar+100;
var space = " ";
var dots = "...";
var stars = "***";
var moretext = "Read More >";
var lesstext = "Read Less";
var count = 0;
var list_limit = 4; // keep this 1 less than what you want
var a = false;

$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {
    count = 0;
    for (var i = showChar; i < b; i++) 
    {
            if (content[i] == space)
             {
                var c = content.substr(0, count);
             }

             count = count + 1;
    }

        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + dots+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});



$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } 
    else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle(animation_time);
    $(this).prev().toggle(animation_time);
    return false;
});
```

I am trying to hide first 100 characters of this div when the page loads but it is only the characters from the paragraph and the list is is not hiding. Plz tell me what to do.I really need help with this may be the var content is not taking the whole html of the div and then it is only removing the characters from the paragraph.

Comment: you said _**I am trying**_ ...well what you have tried..?

Comment: I edited my question see now @Bhuwan

Comment: is it possible to turncate paragraph and list together

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is using jQuery to fetch the string and cut it off. At the ***very*** least, wrap the text in a `<span>` as such

```
<div class="more">
  <p>
    <span class="my-text-wrap">
      //Your text here
    </span>
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

**EDITED**: You can use `.find()` to locate the `<span>` child element of the current `<div>` in the `.each()` loop

```
var showChar = 100; //Number of characters to show

$(".more").each(function() {
  var textWrap = $(this).find(".my-text-wrap");
  var fullText = textWrap.html();
  textWrap.html(fullText.substring(0,showChar));
  $(this).find("ul").hide(); // Hiding the list
}
```

Comment: I can do this with a paragraph but i want it to happen with paragraph and list together. The paragraph and list will be inside div and when page loads i want it to show 100 characters of the paragraph and the list hidden.

Comment: I added the line to hide the list to the example

Comment: do you have any example where you can show and hide a bunch of paragraphs and lists inside a single div.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you wish to do? Does the `showChar` amount apply to the list? Or do you just wish to hide it and truncate the paragraph by `showChar`?

Comment: Here's a pen for both cases, I've commented the click handlers so you can recognize which is which is which.
https://codepen.io/Iodred/pen/wmwzwe